# jQuery on form submit refreshing page

Tags: jquery

I know how this works, I've done it a thousands times. Still, it does not work now. WHY?

I have the following code. I've tried `e.preventDefault`, `e.stopPropagation`, `return false`. I've changed the html for the form to `<form onsubmit="function()"` and so on. Still, every time I submit the form the page refreshes.

Can anyone who can tell me how drunk I am and what I'm doing wrong?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.register-form').submit( function(e){       
        var form = jQuery(this).serialize();        
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : form,
            success : function( d ){
                if( d.success ) {
                   alert( 'Takk for din påmelding' );
                } else {
                   alert( 'Noe gikk galt, vennligst prøv igjen senere' );
                }
            }, 
            error: function(){
                alert( 'Noe gikk galt, vennligst prøv igjen senere' );
            }
        });     
        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

For those who would like a url to the site it is:
http://ccnmn.loke.itvault.no

NB: it's in Norwegian. You'll find the form by pressing 'Priser' in the top menu and then 'Bestill' in the packages shown

Comment: What calls function register?  Asked a different way, how does your code get to where it calls `register()`?

Comment: That would be my latest attempt, onsubmit="register(); return false;". I'll edit my question

Comment: Without context it's impossible to say.

Comment: Where exactly did you put the e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); was the first line of my function. Right after jQuery('.register-form').on('submit', function(e) {

Comment: Updating question with URL for the site

Comment: @OleHaugset both (false & preventDefault) works in [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Y7h0Fu6juuccePTCw8k?p=preview)

Comment: Probably so drunk you forgot to clear your cache.

Comment: Found the error in another JS-file. So not that drunk, just about enough :)

Comment: @OleHaugset - should we close this question since the solution was not related to the posted problem and unlikely to help others in the future? (that's my vote btw, only because of the nature of the answer)

Comment: @Tommy Yes we should :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will not help any other developers by staying on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7606sqez/14/) shows that your code works just fine with the proper `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` in place at the correct locations in the code (also, I changed your variable from `form` to `myForm` just in case there was some weird name collision happening.)  If you mirror this fiddle and still have issues, your problem must lie elsewhere (don't have a handler on the submit button do you?).

```
<form class="register-form" action="/echo" method="POST">
   <input type="Text" id="test" name="test"/>
   <input type="Submit" value="Go" id="TestSubmit"/>
</form>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.register-form').submit(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        var myForm = $(this).serialize();   
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "www.google.com",
            data : myForm,
            success : function( d ){
                if( d.success ) {
                   alert( 'Takk for din påmelding' );
                } else {
                   alert( 'Noe gikk galt, vennligst prøv igjen senere' );
                }
            }, 
            error: function(){
                alert( 'Noe gikk galt, vennligst prøv igjen senere' );
            }
        });
        //return false; would also work here instead 
        //of the event.preventDefault(); above        
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @PHPglue - that is a valid point.  I tested his code using the methods that I use (`event.preventDefault();`) as well as the suggested implementation from jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/submit/ itself.  However, I will update the answer to include that return false also works.